# Excluding a file type from the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have several PSD files stored in my images folder. It's nice to keep these files there for development, but I don't want them to be served. Is there a config somewhere that would allow me to prevent a filetype from being precompiled?

Comment: You can modify your git ignore file to include psd files. https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: Where are you deploying?

Comment: @Justin I like to keep my images in version control so they're easy to share with a team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet might be to exclude these files during deployment. For example, with Heroku if you add a `.slugignore` file to the root of your project you can exclude certain files from being included. This also has the added benefit of decreasing spin up times on Heroku. An example configuration would be:

```
*.psd
*.pdf
doc
```

You should be able to do something similar with Capistrano.

**Edit:**

This post shows how to do something similar for Capistrano deploys:

[Excluding files from being deployed with Capistrano while still under version control with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558249/excluding-files-from-being-deployed-with-capistrano-while-still-under-version-co)

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing. Thanks!